# pybind11 somehow slows c++ function

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

All stackoverflow/github issues I've seen were about speeding up functions calls from Python in case of marshalling objects.
But my problem is about the working time of pure c++ function inside pybind11 C++ module function.

I have the training function that loads dataset and calls train method from the native C++ library class:

```
void runSvm() 
    // read smvlight file into required sparse representation
    auto problem = read_problem( "random4000x20.train.svml" );

    CSvmBinaryClassifierBuilder::CParams params( CSvmKernel::KT_Linear );
    params.Degree = 3;
    params.Gamma = 1/20;
    params.Coeff0 = 0;

    // measure time here
    using namespace std::chrono;
    system_clock::time_point startTime = high_resolution_clock::now();

    CSvmBinaryClassifierBuilder( params ).Train( *problem ); // measure time only for this line

    nanoseconds delay = duration_cast<nanoseconds>( high_resolution_clock::now() - startTime );
    std::cout << setprecision(3) << delay / 1e6 << std::endl;
}
```

I bound this function to Python via pybind11:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(PythonWrapper, m) {
    m.def( "runSvm", &runSvm );
}
```

Then compiled pybind11 module library and called it from Python. The timer value was over 3000ms.
But when I call this function from pure C++, the timer value is around 800ms.
Of course, I was expecting some overhead but not in this place and not so much.

I ran it in one thread and both cases it 100% loaded one core.

Where the issue can be? Who faced the same and how did you handle this?

Comment: Is this repeatable?  Perhaps the C++ version ran faster because the file was in cache.  Are you really comparing two equivalent programs?  For example: are they compiled with the same compiler and the same code optimization settings?

Comment: Yes, test programs are as simple as in this description and I have a local Release build of the library I call Train() from. The same binaries are used to link either c++ test sample or pybind11 module. (not sure about compilation flags from pybind11, but this is unlikely the issue)

Comment: Until evidence proves otherwise, I'm assuming the pybind11 library is somehow not compiled with optimizations.

Comment: @Botje, I checked in CMakeFiles dir, it was compiled with _CXX_FLAGS = -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -fopenmp_. C++sample was compiled with the same flags except _-flto -fno-fat-lto-objects_

Comment: pybind11 cannot slow down a function it calls. Something else must be responsible for the slowdown. It is really difficult to guess what it could be without seeing a [mcve].

Comment: Show the full CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Ok, I will place sample projects on github and add the link. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was working on a reproducible example, I found out that I compare different svm kernels in C++ example (it was based on libsvm params proved 'rbf') and in pybind11 lib (it was hardcoded 'linear'). After fixing it and comparing the same algorithms there was no difference in time.